# ScanResults sets my variable with two Strings but return value only has one

Tags: java, android

```
String essidPrefix = MainFragment.configuration.getEssidPrefix();
    wifiManager.startScan();
    results = wifiManager.getScanResults();
    for(ScanResult scanResult : results){
        String scanWifi = scanResult.SSID;
       if(scanWifi.startsWith(essidPrefix)){
           bssid = scanResult.BSSID;
           //bssid now has two strings, abc123 and abc1234 for example

       }
    }
   //bssid here only returns abc123
    return bssid;
```

As shown in the code, how do I concatenate `abc123` and `abc1234` together from `scanResults.BSSID` so that I am able to return it as one String ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i get your question.

String concat in **Java/Android**..

```
bssid = bssid+","+scanResult.BSSID; // comma separate
```

**Edits**

As per the comments.. you need to reset it. `bssid = "";`
So your code will look like this.

```
List<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>();
String essidPrefix = MainFragment.configuration.getEssidPrefix();
    wifiManager.startScan();
    results = wifiManager.getScanResults();
    bssid = ""; // this will reset it
    for(ScanResult scanResult : results){
        String scanWifi = scanResult.SSID;
       if(scanWifi.startsWith(essidPrefix)){
           // if you want to avoid null
           ids.add(scanResult.BSSID); // comma separate
       }
    }
   //bssid here only returns abc123
    return bssid = android.text.TextUtils.join(",", ids);
```

Comment: hi thanks for your prompt reply, i have tried your method, i am able to get them in one string now but everytime the method runs, it will keep adding. for example for the first time it will be : null, bssid1, bssid2 , on second run of the method, it becomes : null,bssid1,bssid2,bssid1,bssid2. i suppose its because of the ( bssid + )?

Comment: Thanks alot! Finally got it working except tat it will always have a comma infront , like  , bssid1 , bssid2. other than that all is good!

Comment: @JoshuaTan If it works , plz mark it accepted answer. :) and for comma you can try another way.. `ArrayList<String>`.

Comment: @SRBbans thanks alot for the help, really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You should use StringBuilder(Not thread safe) class for concatenation rather using '+' operator (as it consumes more memory).

```
String essidPrefix = MainFragment.configuration.getEssidPrefix();
wifiManager.startScan();
results = wifiManager.getScanResults();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(ScanResult scanResult : results){
    String scanWifi = scanResult.SSID;
   if(scanWifi.startsWith(essidPrefix)){
       sb.append(scanResult.BSSID).append(",");
   }
}
sb.deleteCharAt((sb.length() - 1));
return sb.toString();
```

Comment: hi thanks for your reply, i have bssid = sb.toString(); but all it did was added a comma infront of abc123, abc1234 was not returned together with abc123. :(

Comment: What is scanResult.BSSID return type?

Comment: string @rahul kale